# Number of single precision inputs on IOIO

Tags: android, timer, digital, ioio

Looking at this page it mentions that double precision digital pulse input (32-bit timer) can be divided into 2 single precision 16-bit timers.

https://github.com/ytai/ioio/wiki/Pulse-Input

It says there are 3 single and 3 double modules.

Does this mean that 9 pins can be used for single precision pulse input? (3 single + 3*2)?

Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the existing support code you can do up to 6 (3+3) concurrent channels. You get get to up to 9 single precision channels with some tweaks to the underlying code.

Specifically, in the file software/IOIOLib/src/ioio/lib/impl/Board.java, search for where the Hardware class instances are created and notice that arguments 5 and 6 of the ctor are the double- and single- precision input capture (pulse input) module numbers. E.g.:

```
static final Hardware IOIO0004 = new Hardware(MAP_IOIO0004,
            9, 4, 3, new int[] {0, 2, 4}, new int[] { 6, 7, 8 },
            new int[][] {{ 4, 5 }, { 1, 2 }, { 26, 25 }},
            new int[] { 36, 37, 38 });
```

If you replace:

```
new int[] {0, 2, 4}, new int[] { 6, 7, 8 }
```

With:

```
new int[] {}, new int[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 }
```

You'd get 9 single-precision and 0 double-precision modules, etc.

Comment: Could you describe which class or activity or file in the library that needs to be modified and an idea to what needs to be done?

Comment: Elaborated my answer.